# Do you need to set the model on the controller when using setupController on Ember.Route?

Tags: ember.js

I have been having some confusion in regards to the Ember.Route model vs. setupController. I have an example app here:

http://jsbin.com/ihakop/5/edit

I am wondering why it is that I need to add the following (see inline comment)

```
App.AppsShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return App.LtiApp.find(params.id);
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('reviews', App.Review.find());

    // Why is this line needed? Shouldn't it have the model
    // already on the controller?
    controller.set('model', model);
  }
});
```

Shouldn't the model already be on the controller?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a good question. This behaviour was introduced with RC4. Have a look at this [blog post](http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/05/28/ember-1-0-rc4.html) for explanation. The recommendation of the Ember guys is to add a call to `_super()`:

```
App.AppsShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return App.LtiApp.find(params.id);
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
     this._super(controller, model);
     controller.set('reviews', App.Review.find());
  }
});
```